# How to implement file upload API in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

i was trying out file upload program , i get exception in script mediator  while setting binay = true . following is code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/v1/document" name="DocUpload" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/upload">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.fileName)" name="fileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.fileContent)" name="fileContent" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <ns:binary xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:binary>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/attachments/content"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <script language="js"><![CDATA[var binaryNode =       
                    mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().getFirstOMChild();  
                    binaryNode.setBinary(true);]]></script>
            <log level="full">
                <property expression="$ctx:fileName" name="fileName"/>
            </log>
```

Exception as follows

"fileContent": "Base64 IMAGECONTENT"}/request/mediate/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Envelope

[2020-07-03 17:48:21,346] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator} - The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "setBinary" of null (Unknown Source#3) in Unknown Source at line number 3

I have upload the file using POSTMAN , by calling API  as shown below

[image]

, Any help appreciated

Comment: Hi @Brijesh,

Did you find out solution to upload attachment via WSO2 EI API??

Comment: No , i could upload text file  But not the files formats like PDF , word etc . I used custom mediator for this , using java .

Comment: Hi @Brijesh,
I am also have similar use case, Facing some issue,can you please look into below question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347153/attachment-handling-through-wso2-ei-6-1-1-in-api

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are sending the message body as a header in the postman (request {
"fileName":"imageNew2.png",
"fileContent": "Base64 IMAGECONTENT"
})

Instead of this please try to send the request payload as the body (use a POST request).

[image]

If you are interested in working with files please refer to the VFS transport and also the file connector operation in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kOBd.png), [2].

[1] -https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/VFS+Transport

[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/File+Connector